# Unsolvable Linkage error with openears when trying to run tests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linker, openears

I have been using openears for a while now with no problems. I imported the library into my project and the application compiles and runs.
The problem arose when I tried to create and run tests. The projects refuses to compile and issues the following linkage error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_delete_voice", referenced from:
>         _unregister_cmu_us_slt in OpenEars(cmu_us_slt.o)
>     "_flite_feat_set_string", referenced from:
>         _register_cmu_us_slt in OpenEars(cmu_us_slt.o)
>     "_cg_synth", referenced from:
>         _register_cmu_us_slt in OpenEars(cmu_us_slt.o)
>     "_uttfunc_val", referenced from:
>         _register_cmu_us_slt in OpenEars(cmu_us_slt.o)
>     "_flite_feat_set", referenced from:
>         _register_cmu_us_slt in OpenEars(cmu_us_slt.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OENotification", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RapidEars(OEContinuousModel+RapidEars.o)
>     "_ps_nbest", referenced from:
>         l015 in RapidEars(OEContinuousModel+RapidEars.o)
>     "_cg_db_val", referenced from:
>         _register_cmu_us_slt in OpenEars(cmu_us_slt.o)
>   .
>   .
>   .
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OEPocketsphinxController", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.OEPocketsphinxController in OpenEarsClient.o
>         l031 in RapidEars(OEPocketsphinxController+RapidEars.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried several approaches I found but still haven't found a solution.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to figure it out. Downloaded the latest Openears library and added it as before and it worked.
Apparently, You have to upgrade for it to work on Xcode 8.